# Spring roo, what is equivalent of this finder

Tags: java, spring-roo

Default in the aspectJ file the following finder is coded to retrieve all objects, reports in my case.

```
uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findReportEntries(firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder));
```

It has the following parameters: firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder.
After pushing-in the list method this is the original code:

```
@RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {
    if (page != null || size != null) {
        int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
        final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findReportEntries(firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        float nrOfPages = (float) Report.countReports() / sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
    } else {
        //  uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findAllReports(sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findReportsByActiveEquals(1, sortFieldName, sortOrder).getResultList());
    }
    addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
    return "reports/list";
}
```

In my listing I only want to show the active reports.
So in the Spring Roo console I added:`finder add --finderName findReportsByActiveEquals`
Now I can choose between:

1. Report.findReportsByActiveEquals(active)
2. Report.findReportsByActiveEquals(active, sortFieldName, sortOrder)

The problem is that these generated finder lack the firstResult, sizeNo parameters.

The new code I can come up with is:

```
    @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
public String list(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size, @RequestParam(value = "sortFieldName", required = false) String sortFieldName, @RequestParam(value = "sortOrder", required = false) String sortOrder, Model uiModel) {
    if (page != null || size != null) {
        int sizeNo = size == null ? 10 : size.intValue();
        final int firstResult = page == null ? 0 : (page.intValue() - 1) * sizeNo;
        //  uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findReportEntries(firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        <List<Report> reportsList = Report.findReportsByActiveEquals(1, sortFieldName, sortOrder).getResultList();
        uiModel.addAttribute("reports", reportsList);
        float nrOfPages = (float) reportsList.size() / sizeNo;
        uiModel.addAttribute("maxPages", (int) ((nrOfPages > (int) nrOfPages || nrOfPages == 0.0) ? nrOfPages + 1 : nrOfPages));
    } else {
        //  uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findAllReports(sortFieldName, sortOrder));
        uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findReportsByActiveEquals(1, sortFieldName, sortOrder).getResultList());
    }
    addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
    return "reports/list";
}
```

Why is this a problem?
The effect is that although at the bottom of the list page it says:List results per page: 5 10 15 20 25, always all records are listed.
Also the original finder is not in the Report_Roo_Finder.aj file.

**Question**:
How can I create an equivalent of the original finder, yet only retrieving the active reports.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a good start but your next layer in "Reports" does not support your code enough.

In the original code I see

```
uiModel.addAttribute("reports", Report.findReportEntries(firstResult, sizeNo, sortFieldName, sortOrder));
```

"reports" is limited to an individual page's data

While in your new version I see

```
uiModel.addAttribute("reports", reportsList);
```

"reports" is always all the data.  You need to limit the list of just the data of the page.  I would probably just create my own "finder" method in the java file which is a combination of the

```
Report.findReportEntries
```

and

```
Report.findReportsByActiveEquals
```

So I'd create a

```
Report.findReportsByActiveEqualsWithPaging
```

Sorry I'm not familar enough with the ROO finder to see if you can tell ROO how to build this for you.

I hope this gives you a good start.

Comment: Nanya, did this help or what did you do?